# How to change style of an imported component?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm importing this component into `NewComponent.jsx`

```
import OptionsMenu from "../../components/OptionsMenu/OptionsMenu";
```

where it's rendered as such:

```
                <OptionsMenu
                  options={[
                    {
                      icon: "trash-alt",
                      action: () => this.toggleDeleteModal(index),
                      title: "Delete",
                    },
                  ]}
                />
```

The options menu component uses a file called `styles.js` which has a colour set too:

```
export const OptionsMenuDropDown = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: -200%;
  color: #0F4379;
```

So it's usage would be

```
  <OptionsMenuDropDown>
    <ol>
      {options.map((option, index) => {
        return (
          <li>
            <button className="options-btn" key={index} onClick={option.action}>
              <p >{option.title}</p>
            </button>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ol>
  </OptionsMenuDropDown>
```

Is it possible to change this colour when its being used in `NewComponent.jsx` ? So that I can override it with another colour?

I cannot use a separate .css file for `NewComponent.jsx` but can use a styles.js. There is also a global css file too

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a prop into your styled component, like the color.

```
const OptionsMenu = ({color}) => {
    return (
      <OptionsMenuDropDown color="color">
        <ol>
          {options.map((option, index) => {
            return (
              <li>
                <button className="options-btn" key={index} onClick={option.action}>
                  <p >{option.title}</p>
                </button>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ol>
    </OptionsMenuDropDown>
   )
}
```

Then in your styles.js.

```
export const OptionsMenuDropDown = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: -200%;
  color: ${props => props.color};
```

Then you can use it in you NewComponent passing another color as a prop.

```
const NewComponent = () => {
   <OptionsMenu color="#fff" />
}
```

Comment: Did you mean passing it to `OptionsMenuDropDown` in `NewComponent.jsx`? How can I use your first block of code, because that would fix the colour to color="#0F4379" ?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question. You want to use your OptionsMenuDropDown in multiple places and use different colors, right?

Comment: Yup, thats right. However, if I add the line `<OptionsMenuDropDown color="#0F4379">` where OptionsMenuDropDown is defined then it adds that color to all the places where its used. Thats not what I want

Comment: The point is that you can pass a new color as a prop. I have updated my answer with a use case.